# Error using custom source server with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, source-server

I've indexed a PDB file with source server information. The pdbstr utility dumps out the following srcsrv stream:

```
SRCSRV: ini ------------------------------------------------
VERSION=2
INDEXVERSION=2
VERCTRL=http
SRCSRV: variables ------------------------------------------
HGSERVER=http://repository-srv
SRCSRVVERCTRL=http
REPONAME=clr_foundations
HTTP_EXTRACT_TARGET=%hgserver%/%reponame%/raw-file/%var3%/%var2%/%fnfile%(%var1%)
SRCSRVTRG=%http_extract_target%
SRCSRVCMD=
SRCSRV: source files ---------------------------------------
C:\workspace\clr_foundations_build\clr_foundations\Tests\native_rpc_server\main.cpp*Tests\native_rpc_server*776954c6675e
SRCSRV: end ------------------------------------------------
```

As you see, this instructs the debugger to use the HTTP gateway to our Mercurial server. When using this PDB file with WinDbg, the debugger prompts me for basic HTTP credentials  to access repository-srv and successfully displays the source file. (The same URL also works in a browser window, or with a command-line tool like curl.)

However, when using this PDB file with Visual Studio 2012 (and having enabled source server supports in Tools > Options > Debugging), the debugger does not resolve the file from the source server, prompts me to point to a file on disk, and displays the following error in the output window:

```
SRCSRV: Source server cannot retrieve the source code for file 'c:\workspace\clr_foundations_build\clr_foundations\tests\native_rpc_server\main.cpp' in module 'C:\workspace\clr_foundations_build\clr_foundations\Tests\native_rpc_server\Win32\Debug\native_rpc_server.exe'.
```

There is no additional error information so I am at loss how to further diagnose this. Is there anything else I could do to get more detailed error information, or alternatively another approach I should take?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved the problem.

I had a same problem the last days and could fix it by specifying a Cache directory under Tools/Options/Debugging/Symbols. I think VS needs to know where to save downloaded source files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Visual Studio 2012 elevated, then it will work.